# Find all points on the graph $f(x)=x^2 + 4$ of that have a tangent which passes through the point $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm having trouble understanding the right steps to do the problem:

Find all points on the graph of the function $f(x)=x^2 + 4$ that have a tangent which passes through the point $(0,0)$.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685879/given-point-and-tangent-line

Comment: So far I found the slope using the derivative of the function, and I know how to find the equation of the line, but I'm not sure what else is required to the find "all points."

Comment: Check for which points the tangent line has the point $y=0,x=0$.

Comment: I came up with the P(sq(-2), 4), but I don't feel that this is right. I believe I'm only supposed to deal with real numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Differentiating:

$f'(x) = 2x$. So the slope of the tangent line at $x_0$ is given by $m = 2x_0$.

The equation of line tangent to the curve when $x = x_0$ is given by $$y - (x_0^2 + 4) = 2x_0(x - x_0)\iff y = 2x_0x + \underbrace{(x_0^2 + 4 - 2x_0^2)}_{y\text{-intercept}\, = \,0} \tag{$*$}$$

When does the y-intercept equal zero?  $$4-x_0^2 = 0\iff (2-x_0)(2+x_0) = 0 \iff x_0 = 2,\;\text{or }\,x_0=-2$$

Now, find the corresponding $y= f(x_0)$ values for each of the two solutions. Then your points are given by $\left(x_0, f(x_0)\right)$

Comment: Glad to have helped!